# Tab View not showing in interface builder and compiled app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nstabview

I was adding a component to my tab view in interface builder, when all of a sudden everything just disappeared. All I have left now is an empty "Custom View". However the tab element itself still exists in the sidebar. And I can drag it out of the custom view and it will show up fine. But when I drag it back in, it disappears again. What could the cause of this be?

To that end, I have a lot of issues with tab views in general, a lot of times the tab contents disppears in interface builder, and I have to first click on another tab button and then return to the tab I was working on to make it show again.

Comment: Are you using auto layout or old style springs 'n' struts?

Comment: Are tabs shown or hidden in your tabView? Can you post a screenshot?